# Find the modulo of division of very big numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo

I have to find the modulo of division of this numbers:

239^(10^9) and 10^9 + 13

239^(10^9) and 10^9 + 15

... etc up to 1001;

Using only native libraries in c++. How to do that? As you can see, the first number is about 3 billion symbols.

I tried finding the length of modulo periods, but they are mush longer, than 10, and even `unsigned long long int` can't deal with such big numbers (239^10). Also I think that "big numbers" algorithms (storing a number as an array) will not work for me too (500*10^9) is too much operations.

BTW, this is supposed to work less, than in 5 hours.

Comment: *Is there a way to do that?* Most likely yes but that doesn't help you, does it?

Comment: @RSahu, yes, how did you guess?!?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should look into [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).  It's exactly what you need.  The trick is to *not* calculate the result then divide.

Comment: It should calculate pretty much immediately (i.e. in milliseconds) if you use "Right-to-left binary method" from the Wiki link. (You have only 500 different modulos, and the exponent is only 2^30, right?)

Comment: Modulo periods only work for prime numbers, some of the numbers in the series 10^9 + 13 ... to 1001 are not prime numbers. The answer below should work.

Comment: @Kolmar, yes, I have written this algorithm and it works perfectly (about 0.5 seconds to calculate each number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that:

```
(A*B) % MOD = ((A % MOD) * (B % MOD)) % MOD
```

So

```
(A^n) % MOD = (((A ^ (n/2)) % MOD) * ((A ^ (n/2)) % MOD)) % MOD;
```

And we can do it recursively.

So, here is our function:

```
int cal(int pow, int val, int MOD){
   if(pow == 0)
      return 1;
   int v = cal(pow/2, val, MOD);
   if(pow % 2 == 0)
      return (v*v) % MOD; 
   else
      return (((v*val) % MOD) * v) % MOD;
}
```

Comment: What about numbers in terms of 10^105? How do we handle them.

Comment: Up-voting this because I did not know this and is very helpful but I would like a reference to the name of the mathematical law that defines this.

Comment: @SMeaden You can try to look for number theory